# Main characters actors playing background characters in DW?

Tags: doctor-who, actors

As **Peter Capaldi**, who played Roman merchant Lucius Caecilius Iucundus in 4x02 (2005 serie) and **Freema Agyeman** (Adeola Oshodi, 2x12), are there others main character's actors who played background roles before?

In the 2005 serie and the 1963 one.

**Edit:** Every canon count (I'm not a canon racist :D)

Comment: How far does your canon go? Bernard Cribbins had a relatively - background role in one of the Cushing films: would you count that?

Comment: Yeah, every canon count. I will edit my post to specify it

Comment: Colin Baker (Sixth Doctor) played a minor role during Peter Davison (Fifth Doctor)'s tenure. He actually shot the Fifth Doctor at some point, and later joked that he got the job of playing the Doctor by shooting the incumbent.

Comment: @alexwlchan The answer is in this post, you're right. But I didn't saw it (the elected anser is really giving more than what was expected).